# Animation working very slow in my Firefox 3

Tags: jquery, firefox-3

Look at this code snippet:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){blinkText($('#SendedText')); });

function blinkText(element)
{
    $(element).fadeIn('slow');
    $(element).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/aXMtH/5/

This code works fine in all browsers except Firefox 3.  Why does Firefox show and hide text so slowly? How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: the past tense of "send" is "sent" not "sended" ;)

Comment: one is correct English one is not?

Comment: @Tules Haha yeah. I am not a native speaker. Sorry.

Comment: I don't have Firefox 3 to try this out. But it runs great on FF 7.

Comment: just tryin to help you out, I'm an English teacher by day lol

Comment: by the way you could also optimize your code by doing this `function blinkText(element)
{
    $(element).fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code that could case the slowdown. However, try to change

```
$(element)
```

to

```
element
```

because your `element` is already an jQuery object. If that won't work, that's probably a bug in your Firefox version. It's already version 7 now...

http://jsfiddle.net/aXMtH/6/

```
function blinkText(element)
{
    element.fadeIn('slow');
    element.fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: @Tules: maybe it was the problem

Comment: I doubt it, animations in general tend to be sluggish in older browsers, no offence to you bro, I'm just saying he shouldn't just accept the first answer, it should be the most relevant

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3 is an old browser, there is nothing wrong with your code and you can no more fix this problem than you can alter previous releases of firefox. If it's really bothering you you could use browser detection and do something simpler for FF3 and older

```
// Select Firefox under 3.x
if (jQuery.browser.mozilla && jQuery.browser.version <= '1.9') {
// alternative behavior.
}
```